# Error building C/C++ project in Eclipse: undefined referenced functions

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, makefile

I am making a C/C++ project in eclipse generating the makefile automatically. I get the errors:

/home/globalcom/Desktop/Eclipse/Bi3000_testApplication/Default/../functions/functions.c:22: undefined reference to `bi3000_clearLines'
/home/globalcom/Desktop/Eclipse/Bi3000_testApplication/Default/../functions/functions.c:25: undefined reference to`bi3000_writeDisplay'
/home/globalcom/Desktop/Eclipse/Bi3000_testApplication/Default/../functions/functions.c:28: undefined reference to `bi3000_writeDisplay'
/home/globalcom/Desktop/Eclipse/Bi3000_testApplication/Default/../functions/functions.c:31: undefined reference to`bi3000_writeDisplay'
/home/globalcom/Desktop/Eclipse/Bi3000_testApplication/Default/../functions/functions.c:34: undefined reference to `bi3000_writeDisplay'

where default is the folder generated by eclipse and where it saves the makefile.  I have the include paths of  in project->properties->C/C++ General->paths and symbols well defined and also all the #include in the project seems to be recognised, but I am getting this compiling error.

The function is defined in functions.h and declared in functions.c:

void print_in_display (const char * line1,  const char * line2, const char * line3, const char * line4){

```
const char firstline = 1;
bi3000_clearLines(0,7);

if(line1 != NULL)
    writeDisplay(firstline,     0,0,8,(char *) line1);

if(line2 != NULL)
    writeDisplay(firstline + 1, 0,0,8,(char *) line2);

if(line3 != NULL)
    writeDisplay(firstline + 2, 0,0,8,(char *) line3);

if(line4 != NULL)
    writeDisplay(firstline + 3, 0,0,8,(char *) line4);
```

} The functions (writeDisplay) are contained in librsm.h  . and print_in_display() is called in main()

Thanks in advance

Comment: So, first things first, do you think you have defined the function `bi3000_writeDisplay` yourself? If so could you post your definition, and your decalration and where you call it. If not then could you explain where you think the compiler should get the definition from.

Comment: so are you going to post the relevant code?

Comment: is this a compiler or linker error? if it is compiler error: then most likely you need to fix your includes. if it is linker then you need to fix how your build is doing linking... i.e. tell it what you are linking against and where said libraries are so that the linker can find the linker.

Comment: it's a linker error obviously

Comment: OK, some more questions, the function you have posted about is called `writeDisplay`, but the function in the error message is called `bi3000_writeDisplay`. It's the function `bi3000_writeDisplay` that we need information about. Where is that declared and defined?

Comment: Nop is just the same function. is writeDisplay always. I am just modifying it right now, sorry

Comment: OK, well you said writeDisplay is in librsm.h, what .c file is it in?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming it is C code from file extension. So in this case try using keyword extern and declare prototype of "bi3000_writeDisplay" function in functions.c. Hope this helps.